# how to get sim card number inserted on SIM900A gsm module via arduino uno?

Tags: arduino

i have a situation of getting the sim card number that insert on SIM900A gsm module throught the arduino uno board. i found a way that asking for user to the "AT+CNUM" but i don't really know how to use this command on the arduino code. Is there any other way of getting the sim card number without using any AT command?

Answer (score 0):

> > download "terminal v1.96b"
> >
> > select comport & press connect.
> >
> > tick on CR=CR+LF
> >
> > tick on +CR located beside send button.
> >
> > just write AT+CNUM and press send button.
> >
> > you will get IMSI number.